# Ajax call or php script add spaces to my data result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I trying to display the content of a MySQL TEXT field inside a `<pre></pre>` html markup.
To accomplish that I use an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : webserviceFile,
    data : {
        action : "confFile",
        id : id
    },
    success : function(data) {
        $("#configFile").html(data);
    },
    error : function(e, f, g) {
        return ("An error occure: " + e + "\n" + f + "\n" + g);
    }
});
```

On server Side I have that piece of php :

```
switch($action) {   
    case 'confFile' :
            $value = getConfigurationFile($_POST['id']);
            echo "##$value##";
    break;
}
```

Finally my orignal html file is :

```
<body>
    <pre id="configFile" ondblclick='selectText( "configFile" )'></pre>
</body>
```

So the script does work, now my problem is that on Firefox IE8 and Chromium I have 3 spaces in front of my ajax result. For example, one of the file contains :
`no config file` + the two dashes I add to be sure that it does not come from my php script, in my `<pre>` mark I will end up with :

```
<pre id="configFile" ondblclick="selectText( &quot;configFile&quot; )" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 67px; max-height: 667px; height: auto;">
   ##no config##</pre>
```

And as you can see there's 3 spaces in front of my `##no config##` string.

I'm using the last stable jQuery and watching what the `POST` return with Firebug I do see those spaces, I remove every echo or print in my php code except the one returning the `##no config##` but still those spaces appear.

Do you have any idea on how and why those fµµµµ appears, and do you know a work around for that ?

Thanks

**Edit 1**: Using trim is one solution but the content of the MySQL field is not modifiable and I can't remove white space at the end or at the beginning of that content for displaying.

**Complete answer:**
Remove every spaces before and after the php markup `<?php` and `?>` in all you php files to avoid that behaviour  that should do the trick

Comment: use trim() to remove extra whitespaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure that your server side php file does not have any spaces before the php open tags and if possible do not use '?>'-tags to prevent trailing spaces aswell

Comment: what do you mean by do not use `?>` should I remove that from my php script file ?

Comment: it seems that is does indeed come from my php script because if I remove every inch of code and just put `echo "any value"` it is send correctly to the ajax call

Comment: It was indeed a  space before a <?php markup in one of the included files

Comment: if a file is pure PHP code then you can leave out the ?> at the end of the file. (this is advised, see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 1):

try jQuery.trim() or replace()

```
var newAnswer = data.replace(" ", "");
$("#configFile").html(newAnswer );
```

Comment: not a solution for me, see the Edit and the comment on previous answer